# check for a sequence in a file using ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I wrote ansible playbook to look for a particular text in a file. It looks for that pattern for 2000 seconds and exits after that.

```
- name: check if keyword exist
  shell: 
  cmd: |
     sh -c "tail -n 100 -f play.txt | {sed '/@@@@/ q' && kill $$; }"
  async: 2000
  register: hi
  failed_when: not hi.changed
```

Now, I want to my play to check for another pattern after 1000 sec(during the first 2000 seconds) and fail if that pattern exist.

But I am not sure how can I check for the second pattern after 1000 seconds of the first task going on.

Is it possible in ansible?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can create few asynchronous tasks in Ansible and write some kind of 'pool manager' play to check their statuses, but it's going to be a gross misuse of the tool.

Ansible is not designed for programming. If you need to have some logic (and the thing you want to write is definitively full of custom logic), it's much better to use external tools.

Ansible is good for defining idempotent states of the system (with instructions on how to make this state). As soon as you start to write something else, you are using specialized tools for wrong job.

So, answer is, yes, you can, and no, you should not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a question, so, async module is used to run tasks in parallel, when poll is kept 0. So, does that means if I have 3 tasks and task1 is running in async then as soon as taks1 is triggered the controller will go to task2 and start running it and after they it will go to task3.  Another thing, if I have kept async to 3 mins, will my execution stops after 3 mins?

Comment: Async tasks are run independently of controller. It's almost 'fire and forget' but without 'forget' (you still have JID to query status). You can use Ansible to run multiple asynchronous tasks in parallel, but you (practically) can't manage them. So it's perfectly fine to have 10 async tasks doing something slow (downloading 10G image, running secure erase for HDD, etc), but it's not fine try to make custom logic based on those tasks and their statuses.